# prepared-statement pass by reference error

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I'm not seeing the error and was hoping someone could figure it out:

```
 public static function createMessage($title, $message, $startDate, $endDate, $author, $status){
      //$dbConn is now a mysqli instance with a connection to the database foobar
      $dbConn = Database::getConnection("foobar");

      $stmt = $dbConn->prepare("INSERT into messages(title, msg, date_start, date_end, app_usersID_FK, date_created, activeflag, msg_status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

      if(!$stmt){
           throw new Exception("Unable to prepare the statement");
      }

      $dt = date("Y-m-d");
      $stmt->bind_param("ssssisii", $title, $message, $startDate, $endDate, $author, $dt, 1, $status);
      $stmt->execute();

      return true;
 }
```

Function call

MessageCenter::createMessage("Hello", "Just calling to say hi", "2009-09-12", "2009-09-12", "1", "1");

Error Message is:

Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 8 by reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing your `bind_param` method is actually [`mysqli_stmt::bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). If yes : every parameters (except for the first one) must be variables passed by reference, so they can be "binded".

Like the manual says *(emphasis mine)* :

> `mysqli_stmt::bind_param` --
>   `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` — Binds
>   **variables** to a prepared statement as parameters

This means you cannot pass a value : you have to use variables.

Si, on your case, something like this should do :

```
$my_var = 1;
$stmt->bind_param("ssssisii", $title, $message, $startDate, 
   $endDate, $author, $dt, $my_var, $status);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it! It wanted activeFlag to be a variable. The following works:

```
$dt = date("Y-m-d");
$flag = 1;
$stmt->bind_param("ssssisii", $title, $message, $startDate, $endDate, $author, $dt, $flag, $status);
$stmt->execute();
```